# Django Model serializer returning ID

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i've created the models and serializers as below

serializers.py

```
class ProductCategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCategory
        fields = ['id', 'name']

    @staticmethod
    def get_product_category_name(obj):
        return obj.product_categories.name


class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product_categories = ProductCategorySerializer

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'default_price', 'description', 'product_categories']
```

models.py

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'itw_product_category'
        verbose_name = 'product category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'product categories'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'itw_product'
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    default_price = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    product_categories = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory, verbose_name='product_categories', related_name='products')
```

Now, when i try to create a new model, product_categories returns only the id and not the name, what should i change?

Example:

```
{
    "id": 25,
    "name": "kms",
    "default_price": 932.0,
    "description": "kms",
    "product_categories": [
        5
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the string value in manytomanyfield fields with this method.

> However, since you can update it with its numeric value when you want to update it, you will need to use a method or a separate serializer and view for updating, deleting and creating data to view the data.

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    product_categories = StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'itw_product_category'
        verbose_name = 'product category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'product categories'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: still the same thing even with StringRelatedField

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you. Also, please read [nested relationship](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product_categories = ProductCategorySerializer(many=True)
```